# correlation or co-movement of two time-series in R

Tags: r, time-series, correlation, finance

I have two financial time series, which are showing the same behavior. Frequency and time frame is the same.

I want to prove that they are correlated / prove their co-movement. Is Pearson correlation a good idea? Or are their other ideas? Any help will greatly be appreciated!

Comment: Check out also related threads. Similar questions have been asked a few times before.

Answer (score 4):

Besides using Pearson correlation, you can also use rank correlation such as [Spearman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman's_rank_correlation_coefficient) or [Kendall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_rank_correlation_coefficient) correlation. You can also display the scatterplot of the ranks whose distribution (called the empirical copula) is an estimator of the underlying [copula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)) encoding the `true' dependence between your time series.

In pseudo Python (rather transparent in R):

```
n = len(X) #== len(Y)
Xrk = scipy.stats.rankdata(X)/n
Yrk = scipy.stats.rankdata(Y)/n
plot(Xrk,Yrk)
```

If the points are distributed on the diagonal, then strong (perfect) comovements, if points are distributed uniformly on $[0,1]^2$ variables are **independent** (stronger than uncorrelated).

Comment: thank you. I do not know Python, what you did was just a graphical analysis of a rank, right? I was rather looking for a test and the "right" methodology.

Comment: Yes, just a graphical analysis of the ranks. But this simple graphical analysis has a strong backup from copula theory. Pearson may be fine for your data if they have a Gaussian copula AND Gaussian marginals, i.e. jointly Gaussian. If the marginals are not OR the dependence structure is not (the copula / the scatterplot of ranks), then it is `wrong' to use Pearson. If the scatterplot of ranks looks like an elliptical distribution (Gaussian, Student, etc.) but marginals are weird (not Gaussians), then go for Kendall or Spearman!